# Парсинг галереи изображений из js для android

Tags: javascript, android, парсер, jsoup

Возникла задача спарсить с одного сайта галерею, которая формируется через js. Предыдущие вещи парсил через JSOUP, но со скриптами он не работает. Внешне на странице эта галерея состоит из 2х кнопок навигации(вперед/назад) и самого фото. Впринципе, если посмотреть код страницы через инструмент в хроме, то ссылку на изображение видно, её можно парсить. По нажатию кнопки "вперед", ссылка на следующее изображение соответственно меняется. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей, как решали?